# Getting Altair to work with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vega, altair

Trying to get Altair to work with Jupyter Notebook, I installed it using

```
conda install -c conda-forge altair vega_datasets notebook vega
```

But when I try to do an example plot

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# for the notebook only (not for JupyterLab) run this command once per session
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength',
    y='petalWidth',
    color='species'
)
```

as seen in their [quick start guide](https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/installation.html), I get

```
ValueError: 
To use the 'notebook' renderer, you must install the vega package
and the associated Jupyter extension.
See https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/installation.html
for more information.
```

even though I have installed vega using Conda. I *can* make vega example plots though. I am unable to enable the Jupyter extension though, as Jupyter says it is incompatible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the current release of altair (Version 2.2), use

```
conda install -c conda-forge vega=1.3
```

or

```
pip install vega==1.3
```

and then restart the notebook.

The `vega` python extension was mistakenly updated this week to only support vega-lite 3.0, which is not yet released and thus not yet supported by Altair.

See https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1114 for the initial bug report.

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot for this. For the record, the conda version of this didn't work (but the pip did).

Comment: Thanks – you need to specify the conda-forge channel if it's not in your defaults, as you did in your question. I've edited the answer to be more clear on this.

Comment: Same here, `conda install -c conda-forge vega` & `conda install -c conda-forge vega=1.3` did not work for me (stuck on solving environment for >12 hours; I tried `conda config --set channel_priority strict` as suggested at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8197 but still no luck). However, `pip install vega` did work instantly. Using Windows 10, Python 3.7.6, Conda 4.6.14.