# Altair - Issues setting-up

Tags: python, altair

I only have four-days of python experience. I am running the latest release of Anaconda 1.9.2;

I am trying to run altair, for this I followed the official installation [instructions](https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/installation.html):

```
conda install -c conda-forge altair vega_datasets
```

Using Coda navigator - environments I can see correctly installed are Altair (4.0.1), vega (2.6.0) and vega-datasets (0.8.0);

I have checked al dependencies mentioned on Altair github and manually installed some that were missing (ie m2r and flake 8)

However running the example plot in jupyter notebook;

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# for the notebook only (not for JupyterLab) run this command once per session
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)
```

outputs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchEntryPoint                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\plugin_registry.py in _enable(self, name, **options)
    133             try:
--> 134                 ep = entrypoints.get_single(self.entry_point_group, name)
    135             except entrypoints.NoSuchEntryPoint:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\entrypoints.py in get_single(group, name, path)
    216 
--> 217     raise NoSuchEntryPoint(group, name)
    218 

NoSuchEntryPoint: No 'notebook' entry point found in group 'altair.vegalite.v4.renderer'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5584a45a74ac> in <module>
      3 
      4 # for the notebook only (not for JupyterLab) run this command once per session
----> 5 alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
      6 
      7 source = pd.DataFrame({

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\plugin_registry.py in enable(self, name, **options)
    169         if name is None:
    170             name = self.active
--> 171         return PluginEnabler(self, name, **options)
    172 
    173 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\plugin_registry.py in __init__(self, registry, name, **options)
     23         self.options = options
     24         self.original_state = registry._get_state()
---> 25         self.registry._enable(name, **options)
     26 
     27     def __enter__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\altair\utils\plugin_registry.py in _enable(self, name, **options)
    135             except entrypoints.NoSuchEntryPoint:
    136                 if name in self.entrypoint_err_messages:
--> 137                     raise ValueError(self.entrypoint_err_messages[name])
    138                 else:
    139                     raise

ValueError: 
To use the 'notebook' renderer, you must install the vega package
and the associated Jupyter extension.
See https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/installation.html
for more information.
```

I had found: [Getting Altair to work with Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022136/getting-altair-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook) telling me to downgrade vega to 1.3

This errors out as:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - vega==1.3 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

I guess this makes sense as the answer to this question seems related to an older release of altair;

Am I missing the "vega package and **the associated Jupyter extension**?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the line

```
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
```

This is no longer necessary in Altair 4.0 or newer. You'll have to restart your runtime for the change to take effect.

You can optionally use the notebook renderer by including that line, and it will work as long as you have the most recent version of the `vega` package installed (currently version 3.2). Run

```
pip install -U vega
```

to update it. That won't be available on conda-forge until [this pull request](https://github.com/conda-forge/vega-feedstock/pull/46) is merged.

Comment: Possibly this is not news for the developers of Altair, but could be of interest to others;

I initially adding the line:

'alt.renderers.enable('notebook')'

Because all altair code was initally running into following error:

'Out[1]:
Error loading script: Unable to get property 'version' of undefined or null reference'

However, the actual issue for me was that Jupyter Notebook was starting in Microsoft Edge. Running identical Altair example code in Jupyter Notebook in the firefox enviroment runs perfectly, indeed as Jakevdp mentioned without the notebook renderer line.